# Radio button answer appears in <textarea> but then disappears quickly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Project:

- create 4 radio buttons
- user clicks on an option and submits
- answer should appear in a textarea box

Why is it when I click on a specific radio button option, and then the submit button, the value of the radio button appears in the textarea space for a split second and then disappears?

Thanks heaps!

```js
document.getElementById("clickMePlease").onclick=function() {
    var theOptionPicked;
    var i;
    var nameOption;

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        theOptionPicked = document.myForm.nameQuestion[i];

        if (theOptionPicked.checked == true) {
        nameOption = theOptionPicked.value;

    }

}
 document.myForm.txtOutput.value = "You have picked " + theOptionPicked.value; 

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
        
    <form name="myForm">
    
        <table border=1>
    
    <tr>
    
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="fred">fred
        </td>
    
    </tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="rahul">Rahul
        </td>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="peter">peter
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="none">none of the above
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 100%" type="submit" value="clickme" id="clickMePlease">
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    
    <textarea name="txtOutput" rows=5 cols=20>
        
    </textarea>
    
    </form>
    
    <script>
    

    
 
    
    </script>  
    
    
</html>
```

Comment: when you submit the form the page is reloaded therefore you lose the content of the text area; you might want to have a look a [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in order to fix your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onsubmit="event.preventDefault();"` on your `form` element:

```js
document.getElementById("clickMePlease").onclick=function() {
    var theOptionPicked;
    var i;
    var nameOption;

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        theOptionPicked = document.myForm.nameQuestion[i];

        if (theOptionPicked.checked == true) {
        nameOption = theOptionPicked.value;

    }

}
 document.myForm.txtOutput.value = "You have picked " + theOptionPicked.value; 

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
        
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    
        <table border=1>
    
    <tr>
    
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="fred">fred
        </td>
    
    </tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="rahul">Rahul
        </td>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="peter">peter
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="none">none of the above
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 100%" type="submit" value="clickme" id="clickMePlease">
        </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    
    <textarea name="txtOutput" rows=5 cols=20>
        
    </textarea>
    
    </form>
    
    <script>
    

    
 
    
    </script>  
    
    
</html>
```

Edit:
You was asking for prevent reloading website after submitting form, so I was not checking other functionalitty. Now I repaired and simplified your snippet, so it selects correctly:

```js
document.getElementById("clickMePlease").onclick = function() {

  var theOptionPicked = document.querySelector('input[name="nameQuestion"]:checked').value;

  document.myForm.txtOutput.value = "You have picked " + theOptionPicked;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<form name="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">

  <table border=1>

    <tr>

      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="fred">fred
      </td>

    </tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="rahul">Rahul
    </td>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="peter">peter
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="nameQuestion" value="none">none of the above
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input style="width: 100%" type="submit" value="clickme" id="clickMePlease">
      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>

  <textarea name="txtOutput" rows=5 cols=20>
        
    </textarea>

</form>

<script>
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: I just have another question. For some reason, the bg color keeps changing to purple. I used the exact code above but still not sure why. Any thoughts?

Comment: Purple background? Where? There is not any code which can do that. Could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: See below: https://imgur.com/a/RxcuHl0